# Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing Pre-Build Event..."

Tags: c++, visual-studio, svn

I can't buIld in release mode. Buildlog:

It's somehow related with TortoiseSVN?

```
    Creating temporary file "e:\proj\Client\Release\BAT00000433083800.bat" with contents
[
@echo off

"SubWCRev" "E:\proj\Client\." "E:\proj\Client\Client\Core\CVersionManager_prototype.cpp" "E:\proj\Client\Client\Core\CVersionManager.cpp"

if errorlevel 1 goto VCReportError

goto VCEnd

:VCReportError

echo Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing Pre-Build Event..."

exit 1

:VCEnd
]
Creating command line """e:\proj\Client\Release\BAT00000433083800.bat"""
```

Comment: I see a build log, but I don't see any error messages, only commands that could output error messages. Where do you think the error is?

Comment: According to the error message, there's a problem with your pre-build commands. What's in there ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it yesterday. I had to include binary file from TortoiseSVN to make command line work.